# jQuery - Iterating JSON Object To Find Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, find, element

**SITUATION:**

I have dynamic json object data and need to use it to find element.

Example:

```
[ 
  { "tag": "article",
    "id": "post-316",
    "order": "0" },
  { "tag": "div",
    "class": "entry-content",
    "order": "0" } 
]
```

Its length, keys and values can change anytime based on user request.

I need to use that data to dynamically find the specified element in a web page. The first set of strings will be the data for parent element, which will be used to initialize the search, and the last one will be the target children.

**PURPOSE:**

So, from json example above, I want to find an element with:

*class name* `entry-content`, *tag nam*e `div`, *index* `0` *inside of parent with id* `post-316`

by converting that json data in such kind of format or may be simpler and or better:

```
// because the parent already have attribute id, so no need to check other info of this element    
var elem = $("#post-316").find(".entry-content");

if(elem.prop("tagName") == "div" ) {
   elem.css("background", "#990000");
}
```

**PROGRESS:**

I tried using jquery `$.each()` method but can't discover myself the way to achieve that purpose.

Here is the code where I currently stuck on:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(theJSONData);
$.each(json, function(i, e){
    $.each(e, function(key, data){
        alert(i + " " + key + " " + data);
        if(json.length - i == 1) {
            alert("target " + data);
        }
        if(json.length - i == json.length) {
            alert("parent " + data);
        }
    }
    );
});
```

**QUESTIONS:**

- Is it possible to achieve the **PURPOSE** from that kind of JSON data using iteration?
- If it is possible, how to do it?
- If not, what the way I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a format so the script knows what to get:

```
var data = {
    'id': '#',
    'class': '.'
};

var json = JSON.parse(theJSONData);
$.each(json, function (a) {
    $.each(data, function (b) {
        if (a[b]) {
            $(data[b] + a[b])[+a['order']]; // Element
        }
    });
});
```

---

If you are sure about the data you are getting *(As in it is class, or data, and it will have a tag name)*:

```
var json = JSON.parse(theJSONData),
    last = document;
$.each(json, function (a) {
    var selector = (a['id']) ? '#'+a['id'] : '.'+a['class'];

    last = $(last).find(a['tag']+selector)[+a['order']]; // Element
});
```

Comment: How do I dynamically use the data in this kind of element finder format: `$("#post-316").find(".entry-content");` ?